# Should the Present Perfect be used instead of the Simple Past in the sentence "I was with my sister"?

Tags: tenses

Somebody (not a native speaker) told me that "I was with my sister" is grammatically incorrect and the present perfect tense should be used instead ("I have been with my sister"). Is this true?

Comment: Present perfect is often used with events in the recent past, but there is nothing wrong with using simple past tense either.

Comment: This entirely depends on the context. For example, the present perfect tense is not only grammatically incorrect but sounds very odd in the conversation: *"Where were you yesterday?*" **"I have been with my sister*." But it would be perfectly correct in other conversations. Was there more context that you're not telling us about?

Comment: No, it was just that.